# Alternative to rename option for Stata command esttab that works with ologit

Tags: stata

I am using esttab to export tables from Stata to Latex. I have two specifications, with similar independent variables (x1 and x2 in the code below), which I both want to rename to x and to appear on the same row. For this, I use the rename() option. Everything works fine if I run OLS in both specifications, i.e. if I do the following:

```
eststo model1: qui reg y x1
eststo model2: qui reg y x2
esttab model1 model2, rename(x1 x x2 x)
```

However, if one of the two specifications is ordered logit (using the ologit command), it gives me the error message "equation / not found r(303)":

```
eststo model1: qui reg y x1
eststo model2: qui ologit y x2
esttab model1 model2, rename(x1 x x2 x)
```

Is there an alternative to using rename()? Or another way to fix this? I did not find an answer to this problem.

Comment: Why don't you use the `varlabels()` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rename()` option is having trouble with the cut-point coefficients, which have names like /:cut2, where "/:" is the equation name.

I don't really have a good solution for that (renaming the matrix columns in e(b) and e(V) seems like a pain, there is no `eqrename()` option), but there are two hacks.

If you don't care about them cut-point coefficients, post the margins results and use those with esttab. Alternatively, use `oglm` to "replicate" the output of `ologit`.

Here's an example showing how to do both of these:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo model1: qui reg rep78 weight
ologit rep78 mpg, nolog
eststo model2: margins, dydx(*) predict(xb) post
eststo model3: oglm rep78 mpg, nolog
esttab model1 model2 model3, eqlabels(none) rename(weight x mpg x)
```

This yields:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)             (3)   
                    rep78                           rep78   
------------------------------------------------------------
x               -0.000500***        0.156***        0.156***
                  (-3.58)          (3.58)          (3.58)   

_cons               4.921***                                
                  (11.24)                                   

cut1                                               -0.456   
                                                  (-0.41)   

cut2                                                1.302   
                                                   (1.43)   

cut3                                                3.614***
                                                   (3.75)   

cut4                                                5.231***
                                                   (4.79)   
------------------------------------------------------------
N                      69              69              69   
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: somehow I cannot force my model (due to factor variable use) in oglm, is there a way to use esttab with ologit in a way that the cuts are within the same column (as in your column 3 here)?

Comment: @canIchangethis Open a new question with a reproducible example and tag me in a comment. I will take a look when I get a chance.